# Sign in as a different user access denied

Tags: security

Clicking the "sign in as a different user" link from the system menu in SP 2010 yields an access denied error.

URL is:

```
\_layouts\closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is this a site that was created using the publishing template?

Comment: i think so, its a publishing site for sure

Comment: Are you getting authentication popup when you click on "Sign in as a different user" or is it directly bringing the access denied error? Is it a particular user who is getting access denied error when passing the credentials?

Comment: Have you tried the other url : /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true

Comment: Also check to see if the ViewFormsLockDown feature is enabled. It is by default when using the publishing site template.

Comment: its before the authentication popup, any user is getting it

Comment: this returns an empty page

Comment: The slashes are the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have customized the AccessDenied page, this could be a reason:

"For some reason re-login feature (“Sign in as Different user”) is implemented via access denied page. Click on your name in the top right corner and select ‘Sign in as different user’. You will get access denied page. Strange but it is true!! No idea why it is done this way (other than someone took a shortcut approach).

So now, you need to implement the ‘Sign in as different user’ login in your new accessdenied.aspx page"

See more here:
http://balajinjl.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/customizing-access-denied-page-in-moss-2007/

Comment: Please just dont provide the links, by all means paraphrase or express the answer in your own words, so that it will be like adding more credit to this site rather than navigating to another site for answer. Please do follow as per the below link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: added explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I face a error "Access Denied" when open my aspx page in the popup. Here there is a code:

```
var dialogOptions = {
    url: '/_layouts/TestFeature/Test.aspx?currentUrl=' + window.location.href + '&selectedIds=' + ids,
    title: 'Test popup',
    allowMaximize: true,
    showClose: true,
    width: 550,
    height: 200
};


SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions);
```

I killed whole day searching a solution. And the solution was very simple. I had to delete the first '/' in the url!!!

```
url: '_layouts/TestFeature/Test.aspx?currentUrl=' +
```

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Please create a new question (you can link to this question if you feel they are related)