# Access denied - Let me in!

Tags: security

```
I'm a farm admin
I'm a site collection admin
I'm a member of <site> Owners
```

Access denied logging in (Windows)

What else could it be?

FYI, in system.web

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

SP App Pool is running under a specific windows account

Comment: Are you trying to access this from the server console or another computer?

Comment: im RDC-ed to my VM

Comment: Yes still I face the issue Im getting Access denied error for site collection admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post worked for me

http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2010/02/24/access-denied-for-sharepoint-site-owner/

i can now access the site.

(un?)interestingly enuf tho, this post is still an issue: [Sign in as a different user access denied](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27299/sign-in-as-a-different-user-access-denied)

Comment: I wonder what is the difference between Step 1 and Step 2, They seem to me identical commands. The same command should be entered twice?

Answer (score 1):

You said "im RDC-ed to my VM" so you're accessing the site using IE running on the server (VM) itself right?

I am assuming you're using "Integrated Authentication" (where it's supposed to pick up the windows login) and you're getting 3 prompts for credentials before 401 access denied - in that case its most probably the **local loopback check**.

[DisableLoopbackCheck & SharePoint: What every admin and developer should know.](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Comment: Access is denied, not logon failed...

Answer (score 0):

The first thought that comes to mind is that you haven't set the portalsuperuseraccount and portalsuperreaderaccount.

From powershell:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://webappUrl
$webApp.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]
$webApp.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]
```

If they are empty, check out [Configure object cache user accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx)

Comment: these values are present (but not the user i am trying to login as, its an admin account)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a SharePoint access denied error?

You might want to try using Process Monitor to check whether there are any NTFS file permission issues. I normally run it while the issue occurs, then search for the word "denied".

Other things you can check:

- ULS log (ULSViewer will help) - this is probably your best bet
- Event viewer

Let us know if you are still stuck.